# Qual é a diferença entre Codable e Decodable

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3, swift-playground

Estou com uma certa divida entre Codable e Decodable no Swift.
Em quais situações eu devo utilizar codable e o decodable.

Sou iniciante no Swift e os artigos que encontrei não me ajudaram tanto

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Basicamente é a serialização deles.

Comment: @Maniero mas a questão é em qual situações eu devo utilizar codable ou decodable saca?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O protoco Decodable é implementado para definir a decodificação (deserialização) do objeto a partir de uma representação externa, como JSON, XML ou Plist.
Já Encodable é exatemente o contrário, onde se define como codificar (serializar) o objeto.
Quando o tipo implementa Codable significa que este tem as duas capacidades descrevidas acima.

Criei um playground pra exemplificar a diferença.

O tipo *User* implementa *Decodable*, o que permite criar instancias a partir de um objeto JSON.

*Book* implementa *Encodable*, de forma que objetos desse tipo podem ser serializados, gerando um objeto do tipo *Data*.

Por fim, *Job* implementa *Codable*. No exemplo, codifiquei e depois decodifiquei um objeto desse tipo.

```
import Foundation

struct User: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

let rawData = """
{
    "name": "Rafael",
    "age": 99
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: rawData)
print(user.name)
print(user.age)

struct Book: Encodable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var available: Bool
}

let book = Book(id: 10, title: "Swift", available: true)
let encodedBook = try JSONEncoder().encode(book)
let JSONString = String(data: encodedBook, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
print(JSONString!)

struct Job: Codable, Equatable {
    var title: String
    var salary: Float
}

let job = Job(title: "iOS Engineer", salary: 20000)
let encodedJob = try JSONEncoder().encode(job)
let decodedJob = try JSONDecoder().decode(Job.self, from: encodedJob)
print(job == decodedJob)
```

Esse exemplo é bastante simplista, pois as chaves no JSON tem exatamente o mesmo nome dos atributos do objeto. Caso seja necessário (de)codificar o objeto com chaves diferentes é só definir a enum CodingKeys com o mapeamento entre chaves e atributos

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { ...
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora consegui entender!